# extending Number to get a flags type with instance methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to make a flag-enum and put instance methods on it. Since this is not directly possible with the `enum` construct, I decided to do the following experiment:

```
class SelectionsMade extends Number implements Number {
    constructor(value: any) {
        super(value);
    }

    static get None(): SelectionsMade { return new SelectionsMade(0); }
    static get StartDate(): SelectionsMade { return new SelectionsMade(1 << 0); }
    static get StartTime(): SelectionsMade { return new SelectionsMade(1 << 1); }
    static get EndDate(): SelectionsMade { return new SelectionsMade(1 << 2); }
    static get EndTime(): SelectionsMade { return new SelectionsMade(1 << 3); }

    static startDate(made: boolean): SelectionsMade { return made ? this.StartDate : this.None; }
    static startTime(made: boolean): SelectionsMade { return made ? this.StartTime : this.None; }
    static endDate(made: boolean): SelectionsMade { return made ? this.EndDate : this.None; }
    static endTime(made: boolean): SelectionsMade { return made ? this.EndTime : this.None; }

    inclStartDate(): boolean {
        return (this.valueOf() & SelectionsMade.StartDate.valueOf()) == SelectionsMade.StartDate.valueOf();
    }

    inclStartTime(): boolean {
        return (this.valueOf() & SelectionsMade.StartTime.valueOf()) == SelectionsMade.StartTime.valueOf();
    }

    inclEndDate(): boolean {
        return (this.valueOf() & SelectionsMade.EndDate.valueOf()) == SelectionsMade.EndDate.valueOf();
    }

    inclEndTime(): boolean {
        return (this.valueOf() & SelectionsMade.EndTime.valueOf()) == SelectionsMade.EndTime.valueOf();
    }

    removeStartDate(): SelectionsMade {
        return new SelectionsMade(this.valueOf() & ~SelectionsMade.StartDate.valueOf());
    }

    removeStartTime(): SelectionsMade {
        return new SelectionsMade(this.valueOf() & ~SelectionsMade.StartTime.valueOf());
    }

    removeEndDate(): SelectionsMade {
        return new SelectionsMade(this.valueOf() & ~SelectionsMade.EndDate.valueOf());
    }

    removeEndTime(): SelectionsMade {
        return new SelectionsMade(this.valueOf() & ~SelectionsMade.EndTime.valueOf());
    }
}

let s = new SelectionsMade(SelectionsMade.StartDate | SelectionsMade.EndDate);
console.log(s);
```

Yes, it's a class that extends `Number`, has static getters to imitate the enum values, and some useful instance methods. And this does print `5` in TS playground, though you have to do intermediate cast to `unknown` so the type-checker is silenced.

I have 3 questions regarding this solution:

1. how to avoid the caveat, that you need to call `valueOf` explicitly for TS to accept the class as a number (workaround being type assertion, also not nice)?
2. [Opinions] Would you consider this a valid extension of Number, or would you rather go with static helper functions nevertheless?
3. Is there a way to write modifying functions? e.g. I have the `remove*` methods that create a new value instead of modifying the value they are on, although the latter would be preferable.

Comment: Your question #2 is off-topic for SO, see: [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to avoid the caveat, that you need to call valueOf explicitly for TS to accept the class as a number...

You can't. Your instances are objects, not primitive numbers. You need to use `valueOf` (or a unary `+` or similar) to get the underlying primitive number.

> ... (workaround being a type assertion, also not nice)?

Using a type assertion to treat an instance of `SelectionsMade` as a primitive number would be incorrect. It would just make TypeScript think it was a primitive number, when in fact it was still an object. That has implications for certain operations involving it (not least that `typeof n` would be `"object"` rather than `"number"`).

> Is there a way to write modifying functions? e.g. I have the remove* methods that create a new value instead of modifying the value they are on, although the latter would be preferable.

No. `Number` instances are immutable. There is no way to change the underlying primitive number the instance is wrapped around. You have to create a new instance.